# How to Import a WordPress website to a new domain without having access to original domain's hosting

Tags: wordpress, web, import, subdomain, hosting

I want to export my website to another domain. Let's say my current website is abc.com and it's subdomain is store.abc.com. And the site is on WordPress but I don't have it's hosting credentials. So now I have exported both domain and subdomain's files from tools > export option from WordPress dashboard. And now I want to export this site to another domain. I have already purchased a new domain and hosted my new site on Hostinger. How can I import the whole site with the subdomain one to the new domain?

I have just purchased the hosting and haven't done anything yet. I researched and found out a way to do this: Create a new database and install WordPress. then choose the same theme as the original domain's theme. and from the WordPress dashboard, import the site. Let me know if I should do this. Also, what about the subdomain and any other challenges?